# NEON intrinsics function equal to `VMOV Q1, Q2`

Tags: intrinsics, neon

I want to duplicate `Q2` to `Q1`, but can't find `vmov` funciton.

Just found `VMOVL`, `VMOVN`.

Comment: Just `v1 = v2`, they're C variables you can assign normally, just like you can copy an `int` with `=`.  The compiler takes care of actually doing any necessary `mov` or `vmov` instructions based on which values are actually needed later.

Comment: This is second time your solve my problem. Your answer is correct and accurate.  
You are so humble. I can't move your explanation to `Answer Position`. @PeterCordes thanks a lot.